# Passing dynamic parameter to a string

Tags: php, json, parsing

i am fetching data in json format using a url .

url looks like this (changed parameters in url because i cant post real link)

```
$url = "https://linktosite.com/2.0/items?viewpoint1=11.11%2C11.11&viewpoint2=11.11%2C25.04892279187156&page=.'$page'.&page_size=50&q=schools";
```

i am looping over the data being fetched and after every 50 iterations i have to increment the page number

```
$page = 1; 
$data= file_get_contents($url); 
    $datadecoded= json_decode($data); 
     foreach($datadecoded->result->items as $value){
        if($value->name){
            echo    $value->name.'<Br/>';
        }
            echo $value->contact_groups[0]->contacts[1]->value.'<br/>';

        $count =$count+1;
        if($count ==50){
            $page=$page+1;
        }
     }
```

but it gives me following error

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$result in C:\xampp\htdocs\data\get.php

if i dont increment the number it shows me data for page 1 with 50 results .

Pleas help me to sort it.Thanks

Comment: You're using double-quotes to wrap your url string, and single quotes  pre $page contactenation.

Comment: It says that your JSON does not have `result` property. Try to debug it or just var_dump($datadecoded) and be sure that JSON is as expected. And the reason is in the `page=.'$page'.&page_size` this part. Change it to `page=".$page."&page_size` :)

Comment: this page allows 50 items in a page if i pass more than that it gives an error less than 50 it allows

Comment: @SoufianeHassou i changes but it still does not work